# How do I remove or alter spaces between images in an inline heading in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Here is my code. I haven't finished formatting anything under the heading yet. But I'm trying to get the h2(the one with images) centered and without spaces. I've tried messing with font spaces in parent and removing padding but nothing seems to be working. I only want to do this in CSS.

Code:

```css
body {
  background-color: blue;
}
div {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 25px;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
h2 img {
  display: inline;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <h1>
        Float, Float, Float!
    </h1>
    <div class="nospace">
      <h2>
        <img src="dragon_float.jpg">
        <img src="rootbeer_float.jpg">
        <img src="dog_tubing.jpg">
        <img src="money.jpg">
       </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: try `h2 {
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}` and remove the `margin` for `h2 img` in your code... will add this as an answer if this what you are expecting... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a minor tweak will get what you want.

First, there's space between the images because you put spaces between the images. Any whitespace between the HTML elements will be rendered as a space, so remove the line breaks:

`<img src="dragon_float.jpg"><img src="rootbeer_float.jpg"><img src="dog_tubing.jpg"><img src="money.jpg">`

Second, add `h2` to the style that centers, and remove the left margin on `h2`:

```
h1, h2 {
    text-align: center;
}

h2 img {
    display: inline;
    height: 100px;
    //margin-left:100px;
}
```

That's all that's needed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use:

```
  h2 img {
    display: inline-block; 
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left:100px;
  }
```